# How to get Dataset table column data type in C#

Tags: c#

I have a dataset contains 1 table where i want to iterate loop over the table.

Inside the loop i want to check if Column 1 is date type escape that column and move to next column.Please help me.

```
excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                        //Get the name of First Sheet
excelConnection.Open();


excelSheet = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

string sheetName = excelSheet.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
excelConnection.Close();

string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";

excelCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, excelConnection);
excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(excelCommand);

excelDataAdapter.Fill(excelData);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to get Datatype of Dataset table column:

```
if (Dataset1.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName.ToLower().Contains("date") || Dataset1.Tables[0].Columns[1].DataType.ToString() == "System.DateTime")                              
{
   //Do work;
}
```

Hope you like it.

Answer (score 9):

```
   foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
     {
          if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime)) continue;
          //Execute business logic for other columns
     }
```

Comment: @mlg I only have a DataSet and DataView. Any way to use those instead of a datatable?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]; 

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dc.DataType);
                }
```

To check data types you can also do the following in the loop, even for other data types..

```
                    if(dc.DataType == typeof(System.Decimal))
                    {

                    }
                    else if (dc.DataType == typeof(System.DateTime))
                    {

                    }
                    else if (dc.DataType == typeof(System.String))
                    {

                    }
```